# How to join two tables and fetch complete data against customer brand wise?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables where in one table I have complete product details (Brand and Product name) in other table I have sales detail till date month wise.

in third column I want to have detail of all products against customer brand wise.

For example:

I am selling 4 different models of Samsung phones and there is customer who bought only two models from me. So there is potential that I can sell him other product too for same brand.

I am attaching the image where I have Table 1 and Table 2 and I need the data as per Table 3

I have tried full outer join

```
with cte as
(select Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Customer, ProductMasterfromSales.Brand,ProductMasterfromSales.product
from ProductMasterfromSales
cross join Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable
group by Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Customer, ProductMasterfromSales.Brand,ProductMasterfromSales.product
)
select cte.Customer,cte.Brand, cte.product,
   case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.jan end as jan,
    case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as feb,
     case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Mar,
      case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Apr,
       case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as May,
        case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Jun,
         case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Jul,
          case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Aug,
           case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Sep,
            case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Oct,
             case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Nov,
              case when Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product is null or Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand is null then 0 else Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.feb end as Dev
from cte
left join Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable on Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Customer = cte.Customer and Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.Brand = cte.Brand and Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable.product = cte.product; 


+---------+---------------------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Brand   | Customer            | Product  | Jan  | Feb  | Mar  | Apr  | May  | Jun  | Jul  | Aug  | Sep  | Oct  | Nov  | Dec  |
+---------+---------------------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Samsung | viaCom Technologies | Note 10  | NULL | 1980 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2640 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+---------+---------------------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Samsung | viaCom Technologies | Note 9   | NULL | 0    | 360  | NULL | NULL | NULL | -92  | -8   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+---------+---------------------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Samsung | viaCom Technologies | Iphone 8 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 100  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+---------+---------------------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

[image]

Comment: You should first try yourself and then add that code into your question

Comment: I would start by fixing table 2. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: I have tried with full outer join but it was unsuccessful move as it is only picking product names which are available in both table. 

I am not much expert in SQL queries so if you please guide me with logic please I will surely try and share the code

Comment: There is no full outer join in mysql which makes me wonder if this question is tagged correctly and if it is what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Hi I have edited the Tag, I am using MSSQL 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach: In a cte get the distinct customer's and the unique brands they've purchased from.  Join the distinct values with the brands table on brand (to pick up all of the products (purchased or not).  Then left join the sales (from Table2) on the customer and (all) products.

```
;with cbrand_cte(cust, brand) as (
    select distinct t2.[Customer Name], t1.brand
    from Table2 t2
         join Table1 t1 on t2.Product=t1.product)
select
  cc.[Customer Name], br.Brand, br.Product,
  isnull(sls.jan, 0) Jan, isnull(sls.feb, 0) Feb, isnull(sls.mar, 0) Mar, 
  isnull(sls.apr, 0) Apr, isnull(sls.may, 0) May 
from cbrand_cte cc
     join Table1 br on cc.brand=br.Brand
     left join Table2 sls on cc.[Customer Name]=sls.[Customer Name]
                             and br.product=sls.product;
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate all the customer/product combinations using a `cross join`.  Then bring in the data that exists.

Actually you don't want *all* combinations because you are only looking for brands that customers have.  So `join`ing on `brand` does the Cartesian product that you want.

Try:

```
select cb.customer, cb.brand, pms.product,
       coalesce(smpa.jan, 0) as jan,
       coalesce(smpa.feb, 0) as feb,
       . . . 
from (select distinct smpa.customer, smpa.brand
      from Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable smpa
     ) cb join
     ProductMasterfromSales pms
     on pms.brand = smpa.brand left join
     Sales_Manager_ProductAnalysisTable smpa
     on smpa.customer = cb.customer and
        smpa.brand = cb.brand and
        smpa.product = pms.product
```

Comment: Hi this is throwing error
The multi-part identifier "smpa.Brand" could not be bound.

for Line 
``
 on pms.brand = smpa.brand left join``

Comment: @VarinderVerma . . . Maybe the table names are in the wrong order.  Your question is quite hard to follow, because the names change randomly throughout it.